# How to detect before and after change slide event in jShowoff?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshowoff

I'm using the jShowoff slider, and need to detect the moment before the slide changes and after. Before was an easy one, but I have a problem with detecting the moment when the index of the slide just changed. How can I do it?

I added an id to each slide, how can I write a function to detect when the slide just changed?

```
$("#rotator #slides").append(String.format('<div><a href="{0}" data-additional-url="{1}" data-id="{2}"><img src="{3}" /></a></div>', ob.RedirectURL, ob.AdditionalURL, index, imgSrc));
```

jshowoff:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.jshowoff = function (settings) {
    var config = {
        animatePause: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        changeSpeed: 600,
        controls: true,
        controlText: {
            play: 'Play',
            pause: 'Pause',
            next: 'Next',
            previous: 'Previous'
        },
        effect: 'fade',
        hoverPause: true,
        links: true,
        speed: 3000
    };
    if (settings) $.extend(true, config, settings);
    if (config.speed < (config.changeSpeed + 20)) {
        alert('jShowOff: Make speed at least 20ms longer than changeSpeed; 
the fades aren\'t always right on time.');
        return this;
    };
    this.each(function (i) {
        var $cont = $(this);
        var gallery = $(this).children().remove();
        var timer = '';
        var counter = 0;
        var preloadedImg = [];
        var howManyInstances = $('.jshowoff').length + 1;
        var uniqueClass = 'jshowoff-' + howManyInstances;
        var cssClass = config.cssClass != undefined ? config.cssClass : '';
        $cont.css('position', 'relative').wrap('<div class="jshowoff ' + 
uniqueClass + '" />');
        var $wrap = $('.' + uniqueClass);
        $wrap.css('position', 'relative').addClass(cssClass);
        $(gallery[0]).clone().appendTo($cont);
        preloadImg();
```

(some settings)

```
if (config.links) {
       var handle = uniqueClass != undefined ? uniqueClass : 
uniqueClass2;
                $('.' + handle + '-active').removeClass(handle + '-active 
jshowoff-active');
                $('.' + handle + '-slidelinks 
a').eq(counter).addClass(handle + '-active jshowoff-active');
            };
        };
```

here my alert with beforechange statement

```
function transitionTo(gallery, index, uniqueClass2) {
alert("beforechange");           //alert
var oldCounter = counter;
            if ((counter >= gallery.length) || (index >= gallery.length)) {
                counter = 0;
                var e2b = true;
            } else if ((counter < 0) || (index < 0)) {
                counter = gallery.length - 1;
                var b2e = true;
            } else {
                counter = index;
            }
};

        function isPlaying() {
        return $('.' + uniqueClass + '-play').hasClass('jshowoff- 
paused') ? false : true;
        };

        function play(src) {
            if (!isBusy()) {
                counter++;
                transitionTo(gallery, counter, uniqueClass);
                if (src == 'hover' || !isPlaying()) {
                    timer = setInterval(function () {
                        play();
                    }, config.speed);
                }
                if (!isPlaying()) {
                    $('.' + uniqueClass + '- 
play').text(config.controlText.pause).removeClass('jshowoff-paused ' + 
uniqueClass + '-paused');
                }
            };
        };
return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The plugin author should provide hooks for the before and after moment. I'm looking at this as a potential pull request!! In the mean time, I can shamelessly plug my own jQuery slider that does have options for running code immediately before and immediately after the slide occurs. http://www.multislider.info/#events

Comment: Yeah I know, but unfortunately there are no hooks and the slider is working fine in a bigger project. I would rather try to add some code than change the whole plugin.

Comment: If you can create and post a working example in a JSFiddle, I might be able to help.

Comment: @TJBlackman my sample https://jsfiddle.net/nikolson/1emr765f/2/

Comment: Are you the plugin Author? If not, do you mind editing the original plugin code?

Comment: No, I'm not Author, but I guess there is no other way than editing the original plugin code :)

Comment: @TJBlackman can u help? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer here is to **use a more reputable and feature-rich** jQuery plugin. There are many (hundreds probably) jQuery slideshow plguins that are written very very well, are very efficient, and offer many features and hooks you can use to add your own custom functionality.

[Here's 7 Great jQuery Slideshow Plugins](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/542/top-7-best-jquery-image-and-content-sliders-plugins)

I'm not trying to be mean, but using these two jQuery plugins in tandem the way they are being used is very very inefficient, and the code in the plugins is already not great. It's not horrible, and it works, but there are much much better plugins available. Don't waste your own time re-inventing the wheel!

Ok - All that being said, I slapped some code into your plugins and updated your fiddle. I added this comment everywhere I added code `// *added*` so you can see what I did. Basically, the options for the `jsshowoff` plugin now has two extra settings. Just put your code there, and it will fire once before and once after each animation.

```
$("#features").jshowoff({
    links: true,
    speed: 5000,
    effect: 'fade',
    hoverPause: false,
    beforeSlide: () => {
        // add before stuff here
    },
    afterSlide: () => {
        // add after stuff here
    }
});
```

You will need to copy my javascript from the JSFiddle and update the js in your project.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1emr765f/5/)

Comment: I understand, but thanks a lot anyway, you're the best! :)